# Rails conditional form_form controller and action parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, conditional-statements, form-for, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Maybe I'm going against convention here, but I have a form used by multiple controllers and I want to customize where the submit action gets sent.

I have tried:

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :form_type %>
  <% form_type = local_assigns[:form_type] %>
<% end %>
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :form_action %>
  <% form_action = local_assigns[:form_action] %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for :my_form, url: { controller: form_type, action: form_action } do |f| %>
# OR #
<%= form_for :my_form, url: { controller: "#{form_type}", action: "#{form_action}" } do |f| %>
```

and something like:

```
<% if form_type == 'type_A' %>
  <%= form_for :my_form, url: { controller: 'controller_A', action: 'action_A' } do |f| %>
<% elsif form_type == 'type_B' %>
  <%= form_for :my_form, url: { controller: 'controller_B', action: 'action_B' } do |f| %>
<% elsif form_type == 'type_C' %>
  <%= form_for :my_form, url: { controller: 'controller_C', action: 'action_C' } do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Neither works, the second one for obvious reasons. Any workaround? Should I be using the form_tag instead? Not all my forms are tied to objects. I was also trying to avoid having to nest this template inside another one (the outer template containing the correct form_for parameters). As a last resort, I suppose I could use raw html forms.

BONUS ...Haven't gotten there yet, but I will probably also need to modify the form_for key, in this case 'my_form' (above).

Comment: Is it common form ? if it is then why don't you make a common partial for it? and pass essential parameters as method, url, object with locals? conditionally

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your logic. The form elements are almost exactly the same (with some small tweaks), it's just a different controller/action that needs to process the form. Can you give an example of your suggestion? Right now, the form_controller and form_action are being passed in as parameters (see local_assigns).

Comment: As per me, I would go putting all the form fields and submit button inside one partial and then rendering that partial inside each template with its own `form_for`. It will save a lot of complexity.

Comment: @user58446 Please have a look to example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a common partial for common form example

_common_partial.html.erb

```
<%= form_for object, url: url do |f|%>
  #.. form fields
<%end%>
```

Render this partial conditionally

```
<% if form_type == 'type_A' %>
  <%= render 'path/common_partial', object: form_for_object, url: path_to_which_form_be_submitted%>
<% elsif form_type == 'type_B' %>
  <%= render 'path/common_partial', object: form_for_object, url: path_to_which_form_be_submitted%>
<% elsif form_type == 'type_C' %>
  <%= render 'path/common_partial', object: form_for_object, url: path_to_which_form_be_submitted%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why have three different code paths that do the exact same thing instead of just `if ['type_A', 'type_B', 'type_C'].include?(form_type)`?

Comment: The way I'm thinking of things, perhaps incorrectly, is that I would call the correct layout with only the form_for line, an end, and render: partial (containing the form fields) in between. Would that work? The form fields are what I am trying to re-use in this case. In your example, I will have to replicate all the form_fields for each partial.

Comment: @user58446 SO do you have different fields in each form?

Comment: Sorry, not different form fields, only the html is slightly different (nothing I can't handle easily with conditionals)... and also the controller/action for the form_for.

Comment: In this case it seems like I should just have a different partial for each form_for I need, and then have them all call the same child partial (containing the form fields and html) with the whatever params I want.

Comment: in that case you could pass controller action or path to which form will be submitted  with the partial. example `<%= render 'path/common_partial', object: form_for_object, path: path_to_submitted%>` and common partial `<%=form_for object, url: path%>`

Comment: Does this need to be an ActiveRecord object, or will it work without them? Pretty sure they just represent the base key of the params hash anyways. Also, can you update this example in the comment above in your answer, it's a little hard to read/understand in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @user58446 So far as i know form_for need model's object. and sure am updating the answer, check it.

Comment: @user58446 Btw feel free to upvote/accpet answer if it helped you. :D